# Word: Continuous numbering for specific lower heading level

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'd like to create a certain structure in a book in Word 2010, which should lead to a table of contents similar to:

```
  1 Introduction
I First part of the book
  2 A chapter
    2.1 Some section
        2.1.1 Some subsection
        2.1.2 Another subsection
    2.2 Another section
  3 Another chapter
    ...
II Second part of the book
  4 Yet another chapter
  5 A chapter

  6 Conclusion
```

In order to achieve this, I have redefined the numbering for 'Heading 1' to roman numbers and eliminated the current level 1 number from the depcition of all lower-level heading numbers.

However, naturally, a 'Heading 2' will start with value '1' after a 'Heading 1', for instance leading to

```
  1 Introduction
I First part of the book
  1 A chapter
    1.1 Some section
    ...
```

My question is: Is there a way to *automatically* increment the 'Heading 2' further?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you setup your Table of Contents as a series of TOC fields that are defined by Bookmarks in your document. Don't use multilevel numbered Heading list to try and define segments of the manuscript such as Introduction, Part I, Part II, etc., but again use Bookmarks to define the segments, and multiple TOC fields for the display of the Table of Contents.

Below is an example from a training guide I created and it uses this technique to define chunks of the document's content.

[image]

Reading the TOC field ... `\o "1-2"` is referring to Outline levels to use in the 
TOC portion. So, in this example the Introduction segment TOC will list Heading 1 and Heading 2 styles from the bookmarked area, whereas the Modules segment will pickup Headings 1 - 9 that are contained within the bookmarked area. The `\b "IntroductionSection"` control gives the name of the bookmark that defines this segment of the document.

When using this technique, use multilevel chapter numbering on your Heading levels, and Chapters should be Heading 1, followed by Sections within the chapter as Heading 2. On the Table of Contents page in your manuscript, enter in the descriptions for each segment and follow the description with the appropriate TOC entry.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going with the Multi-Level List.

Start the roman numeral as heading 1, then the Heading 2 becomes the  numeral 1 heading, etc.

Note that the Heading 1 and 2 do not "restart the list after"

Heading 3 restarts after 2, Heading 4 after 3, etc.

[image: Sample of page with headings]

[image: Multi-Level List Editor]

You only need to remember that the headings produce one level lower than you're accustomed to.